# Calling two parent controller scope function from child controller, one after another in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, methods, controller, angularjs-scope, parent-child

I have one Angular.js method from child controller, where it makes a call to twop parent controller methods one after another. But the second function should get the account data from from the first function and then will update call data like below:

```
filter.filterAccountsByProductMetrics1 = function(productWithSegmentations12) {
    accountService.fetchAccountForRecordType([filter.selectedHcpHco.Name.display])
    .then(function(resp) {  
        $scope.accountDataUpdate({
            accounts: resp.data
        });
        var productId = null;
        if(filter.selectedMySetupProduct.Product_vod__c) {
            productId = filter.selectedMySetupProduct.Product_vod__c.value;
        }
        callService.getCallsForProductId(productId)
        .then(function(calls) {
            filter.filterRecords[filterType.product.value] = calls;
            $scope.callDataUpdate({
                calls: applyAllFilterOnCalls()
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I've checked both the functions are getting called but the sequence is not maintained. How to make sure the two parent functions get called one after another.

EDIT: function accountDataUpdate:

```
call.accountDataUpdate = function(accounts) {
    call.accounts = accounts;
    getCallDetails(getCallIdsFromCallsForFilteredAccount())
    .then(function() {
        updateProductFrequencyTableData();
        updateAccountDetailData(true);
    });

    updateDailyFrequencyChartData();
    updateWeeklyFrequencyChartData();
    updateCallFrequencyTableData();
    updateAccountFrequencyData();

    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('updateDoughnutChart');
        $scope.$broadcast('updateBarChart');
    });
};
```

Comment: Is `$scope.accountDateUpdate()` a non-blocking asynchronous function?

Comment: @ georgeawg, Yes, it is not returning any promise, i've updated the question with the code for the accountDataUpdate function

Answer (score 1):

Modify `accountDataUpdate` to return a promise:

```
call.accountDataUpdate = function(accounts) {
    call.accounts = accounts;
    var promise = getCallDetails(getCallIdsFromCallsForFilteredAccount())
      .then(function() {
        updateProductFrequencyTableData();
        updateAccountDetailData(true);

        updateDailyFrequencyChartData();
        updateWeeklyFrequencyChartData();
        updateCallFrequencyTableData();
        updateAccountFrequencyData();

        return $timeout(function() {
            $scope.$broadcast('updateDoughnutChart');
            $scope.$broadcast('updateBarChart');
        });
    });

    return promise;
};
```

Then use that promise for chaining:

```
filter.filterAccountsByProductMetrics1 = function(productWithSegmentations12) {
    return accountService.fetchAccountForRecordType([filter.selectedHcpHco.Name.display])
      .then(function(resp) {  
        return $scope.accountDataUpdate({
            accounts: resp.data
        });
    }).then(function() {
        var productId = null;
        if(filter.selectedMySetupProduct.Product_vod__c) {
            productId = filter.selectedMySetupProduct.Product_vod__c.value;
        }
        return callService.getCallsForProductId(productId)
    }).then(function(calls) {
        filter.filterRecords[filterType.product.value] = calls;
        return $scope.callDataUpdate({
            calls: applyAllFilterOnCalls()
        });
    });
};
```

Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.

It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).